# RavenDB doesnt work with FQDN

Tags: ravendb

We are using RavenDB installed as windows service. All of the apps connect to Raven using the IP .

I was trying to use the FQDN for the machine instead of using IP in the app configurations, but when I use the FQDN I get following error. Not able to nail down whats going wrong.

Have read articles that suggests change of web.config for the authentication.

**If authentication or config is issue how does it work with IP and fail with FQDN ?**

any help/ pointer appreciated

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1 getResponse)
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson()
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectPut(RavenJObject metadata, String key, Etag etag, RavenJObject document, OperationMetadata operationMetadata)
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass13.<Put>b__12(OperationMetadata u)
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.TryOperation[T](Func`2 operation, OperationMetadata operationMetadata, OperationMetadata primaryOperationMetadata, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result, Boolean& wasTimeout)
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, String primaryUrl, OperationCredentials primaryCredentials, Int32 currentRequest, Int32 currentReadStripingBase, Func`2 operation)
   at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, Func`2 operation)
   at Raven.Client.Document.HiLoKeyGenerator.PutDocument(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, JsonDocument document)
   at Raven.Client.Document.HiLoKeyGenerator.GetNextRange(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands)
   at Raven.Client.Document.HiLoKeyGenerator.NextId(IDatabaseCommands commands)
   at Raven.Client.Document.HiLoKeyGenerator.GenerateDocumentKey(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, DocumentConvention convention, Object entity)
   at Raven.Client.Document.MultiTypeHiLoKeyGenerator.GenerateDocumentKey(IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, DocumentConvention conventions, Object entity)
   at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Initialize>b__2(String dbName, IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, Object entity)
   at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentConvention.GenerateDocumentKey(String dbName, IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands, Object entity)
   at Raven.Client.Document.GenerateEntityIdOnTheClient.GenerateDocumentKeyForStorage(Object entity)
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.StoreInternal(Object entity, Etag etag, String id, Boolean forceConcurrencyCheck)
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.Store(Object entity)
   at Insight.RavenDB.RavenPersistenceEngine.Persist(IPersistableObject pe)
The target principal name is incorrect
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode)
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob)
   at System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate)
   at System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest webRequest, ICredentials credentials)
   at System.Net.AuthenticationManager.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)
   at System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean& disableUpload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably this issue:

http://ayende.com/blog/16385/more-auth-issues-0xc000006d-on-windows-2008-r2

Comment: thanks for reply - unfortunately wouldn't be able to do much on registry on the particular box as of now. 

BTW I am using build2375 (installed as service)  do you think that build could be problematic ? going to check known issues with 2375

Comment: The issue is the way Windows processes Windows Auth, nothing RavenDB can do about it. See the linked support article from the blog post.